# Why does Windows 7 Guest on Virtualbox need Installation Media?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I installed Windows 7 on Virtualbox with USB (raw disk), and whenever starting computer, I need the USB(actually a SDCARD) plugged in. Else I get error: FATAL INT18 error. What should I do? Its already installed on 500GB HDD. I will use this computer for server, and Im not sure how stable the SDCARD reader is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading/understanding your question right, this is something you could check: On the **System** settings for the Windows 7 VM make sure the **Boot Order** has the Hard Disk as the primary boot device. Untick the rest if you won't be using them anytime soon.

You should also make sure that you don't have the Windows 7 iso mounted in the **Storage** settings.

[image: VM Settings]

Comment: well, 1 HDD = a VMDK of the SDCARD (installation media), 1 HDD = a VDI with Windows 7 installed. the VDI needs the VMDK when startup. its not a boot order problem, sorry.

Comment: Have you checked whether or not you have the .iso mounted in the Storage settings?

Comment: its no ISO, I did VMDK out of raw physical HDD (a SDCARD). the SDCARD already had Windows 7 installation files on it

Comment: Ah, ok. On some forums users are reporting that they had to mark the partition as active and let System repair do its thing. See this link: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=43939